# How to use REGEXEXTRACT for day and time?

Tags: regex, datetime, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, ifttt

I am using a third-party app that allows me to log in my day, time and location at the push of a button, on a google sheet.

[image]
<sub>(source: [imggmi.com](https://cdn1.imggmi.com/uploads/2019/6/15/8b8a3ec4eb685e033c37cd4d4b87df01-full.png))</sub>

While the app catches these three elements (day, time, and location), I can only see day and location because of the formula that is being used.

[image]
<sub>(source: [imggmi.com](https://cdn1.imggmi.com/uploads/2019/6/15/eac8cfb6350a72652f4ab8964f2b61bb-full.png))</sub>

Is there a way to modify the formula to display both the date and time?

Comment: Here it is: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/13-1TjKYkBzcVCnWP7Yxejf2U9hem6RHeJFFpiDAazDk/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=TO_DATE(DATEVALUE(REGEXEXTRACT("June 14, 2019 at 11:52AM", "\w+ \d{2}, \d{4}"))+
         TIMEVALUE(REGEXEXTRACT("June 14, 2019 at 11:52AM", "at (.*)")))
```

[image: 0]